# Laravel Database Backup to Dropbox with Button

Tags: laravel, backup, dropbox

I install this to my laravel project:

```
backup-manager/laravel
league/flysystem-dropbox
```

for i can backup my database to dropbox, but it's can be done by terminal with php artisan, how to make a button on my setting page that when i click, it can call this backup function?

is there a function that i can call to trigger this backup function? or it's just can be done by php artisan?

i try to run

```
Artisan::call('db:backup');
```

and show error

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

when i run from terminal it's work fine

how to run this from my controller?

```
php artisan db:backup --database=pgsql --destination=dropbox --destinationPath=`date +\%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s`-digitization.sql --compression=null
```

please someone help me..

this is my script with ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#backup").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).data("url");

        $.ajax({
            url: url
        }).done(function() {
            alert("asdsad");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

You can call artisan command from [code itself](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code).

something like ,

```
Route::get('/backupdatabase', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('db:backup');
}
```

If your DB size is so large it maynot works from browsers , so better to use with cron jobs. you can find cron jobs setup documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling). also some [packages](https://github.com/CoreProc/laravel-db-backup).

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can call artisan commands via code. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

So if you need to run this

> php artisan db:backup --database=pgsql --destination=dropbox --destinationPath=`date +\%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s`-digitization.sql --compression=null

Then you could do something like this:

```
Route::get('/db_backup', function () {
    var $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('db:backup',
        [
            '--database' => 'pgsql',
            '--destination' => 'dropbox',
            '--destinationPath' => $now->toDateTimeString().'-digitization.sql',
            '--compression' => null
        ]
    );
});
```

Comment: it's keep loading until i get error because maximum execution more that 60 seconds, what happen? @vonec

Comment: @yudijohn it may timeout if you're db size is large, so try to put it via Cron Jobs.

Comment: if i'm using cron, then the backup run automaticly? so i can't serve backup button? @vonec

Comment: @yudijohn If you need a button you could try calling the backup method via ajax instead of a normal form post.

Comment: edited answer to provide example with the parameters

Answer (score 0):

1) in blade create a button :

```
 <button onclick="backup()"></button>
```

2) in javascript section :

```
var token = $('input[name = _token]').val();
    function backup() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/admin/system/db-backup',
            data: {
                _token: token,
            },
            success: function (result) {
              alert("ok")

            },
            error: function (errors) {

               alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

3)in routes.php :

```
  Route::post('/admin/system/db-backup', [
        'as'   => 'system.dbBackup',
        'uses' => 'Website\SystemController@postDbBackUp'
    ]);
```

4)in controller (SystemController.php) :

```
public function postDbBackUp () {
   $now =  Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d-H-m-i").'-backup.sql';
    try {
        Artisan::call('db:backup',
            [
                '--database' => 'mysql',
                '--destination' => 'local',
                '--destinationPath' =>$now,
                '--compression' => 'gzip'
            ]
        );
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        return Response::json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => ""
        ], 400);
    }
    return Response::json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'success'
    ]);

}
```

Comment: error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Carbon' not found

Comment: if i change corbon with controller name then this error showing  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::now()